# C# .. Asynchronous Sockets .. where is the State Object Stored?

Tags: multithreading, memory, sockets, memory-management, asynchronous

A *simple* question really, but one where I cannot find any anwsers too.

When I execute an Asynchronous Socket operation, such as :

```
socket.BeginSend
(
    new byte[]{6},                // byte[]        | buffer
    0,                            // int           | data to send buffer offset
    1,                            // int           | data to send length
    SocketFlags.None,             // enum          | dunno :)
    new AsyncCallback(OnSend),    // AsyncCallback | callback method
    STATEOBJECT                   // object        | ..state object..
);
```

It works, and when complete it invokes the AsyncCallback parameter, passing with it an IAsyncResult.

```
void OnSend(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    object STATEOBJECT = ar.AsyncState as object;
    /*
        Process the socket operation
    */
}
```

SO..

When the socket operation is being executed 'asynchronously' I know from various sources that the buffer is pinned in memory.

**However I do not know where the 'state object' is stored?**

why?  because I am wondering what the effect of large 'state object's will have?

Taa!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is C#, the object is stored where is allocated :)

The real question should be: who has a reference to the object during the async operation? The coarse answer is: the framework. A more precise answer is that your object is ultimately referenced by the [OVERLAPPED](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684342(VS.85).aspx) structure, through a mixture of managed and native data types, and the OVERLAPPED structure is kept in a list in the kernel.

Comment: If you want to learn about what's *really* happening, get a copy of Inside Windows by Solomo/Russinovich. If you want to use the async IO performantly, go over the articles linked in http://rusanu.com/2008/11/11/high-performance-windows-programs/. The concepts apply to Managet .Net/C# just as well.

Comment: Thanks Remus, £4.26 used on amazon :)

Comment: If you're willing so shell out the moneys, you should go for the fifth edition. http://www.amazon.com/Windows%C2%AE-Internals-Including-Windows-PRO-Developer/dp/0735625301/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1258758082&sr=8-2 Althouh old editions (2000 and up) are also very usefull and will cover at least 80-90% of the basics.

Comment: thanks for the information Remus, think I will digest the 2000 3rd edition first :) then compare.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

It is stored where you created it, on the Heap. And it will not move unless the GarbageCollector finds that necessary. You are just handing out a reference to the BeginSend() method, and you get it back in the OnSend[Complete]() method.